# how to get older versions of mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

So I did `sudo apt-get install php5-mongo` and when I do `composer require "mongodb/mongodb=~1.0.0"` I get this:

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ~1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0].
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
```

When I do `dpkg -s php5-mongo` I get this:

```
Package: php5-mongo
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: php
Installed-Size: 326
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: php-mongo
Version: 1.4.5-1build1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), phpapi-20121212
Conffiles:
 /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini f2a4848fe0856c5bbaf2afc4aee7a1b9
Description: MongoDB database driver
 This package provides an interface for communicating with the MongoDB database
 in PHP.
Original-Maintainer: Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.org>
Homepage: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center
```

So is the problem my ext-mongodb install is too new? Based on the output of dpkg I'd guess I'm running ext-mongodb 1.4.5 instead of the 1.1.0 required by https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library

edit: `echo phpversion('mongo')` gets me 1.4.5 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just uninstalled the apt-get installed version of php5-mongo and installed it with pecl per http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-driver/#installation.

That was for sure more annoying since I had to manually install all of the dependencies. None-the-less, if apt-get isn't installing anything usable in Ubuntu 14.04 it seems like they ought to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

I openend a request at Ubuntu Launchpad to get the new php-mongodb driver also for trusty-universe (Ubuntu14). Its available in xenial but built against PHP7 API. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-mongodb/+bug/1579815